# For what functions does Nash inequality becomes equality?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

For what functions does [Nash inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality) becomes an equality? Also any comment on the regularity of these functions (weak solutions to equality)?

Also same question about Poincare inequality.

Comment: I searched google extensively and could not find anything about when equality is achieved. Hence I am posting this question.

Comment: You may consult the paper of Carlen and Loss
https://academic.oup.com/imrn/article-abstract/1993/7/213/759517?redirectedFrom=fulltext

Comment: Check the papers "Best constants for Gagliardo-Nirenberg
inequalities and applications to nonlinear
diffusions" by Del Pino and Dolbeault and "A mass-transportation approach to sharp Sobolev and Gagliardo–Nirenberg inequalities" by Cordero, Nazaret, and Villani.